# Vertica identity column datatype change

Tags: vertica

In vertica I want to change the datatype of the identity column. For example

```
CREATE TABLE t1(x IDENTITY(1) ,y INT)
```

Is there a way to change the identity column incremental value from 1 to say 10000.

I create the above table now I increment the identity column `x IDENTITY(1)` to `x IDENTITY(10000)`

I tried below sql but it does not work

```
alter table t1  alter column x SET DATA TYPE IDENTITY  ( 10000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/column-constraint.htm):

> You cannot change the value of an IDENTITY column once the table exists.

The available parameters for `IDENTITY` are:

> ```
> IDENTITY [ ( cache ) | 
> ( start, increment[, cache ] ) ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better "create" your table again with new identity properties and after that copy data from last table to new one.